# Why does my Xamarin Forms iOS app fail to open in release mode when launched from Visual Studio?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator, release-mode

I can launch it by clicking the app on the iPhone simulator itself, and have no issues launching from Visual Studio in debug mode.

Errors: 0, warnings: 0.

The message in my Application output reads:

> error HE0042: Could not launch the app [appName] on the device 'iOS
> 14.2 (18B79) - iPhone 12 mini': The request to open [app] failed.

My simulator’s system.log  reads:

> com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.E4CA5C26-862D-4D54-8692-6E6C097A3877[1192]
> (UIKitApplication:com.fern.app[1e6f][rb-legacy][1424]): Service could
> not initialize: 20B50: xpcproxy_sim + 10650
> [839][24AD6C58-C8BA-3A6E-94A2-DBC1AB4FF4B2]: 0x1 Dec  4 17:11:36
> Ferns-iMac syslogd[1194]: ASL Sender Statistics Dec  4 17:11:36
> Ferns-iMac
> com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.E4CA5C26-862D-4D54-8692-6E6C097A3877[1192]
> (UIKitApplication:com.fern.app[1e6f][rb-legacy][1424]): Service exited
> with abnormal code: 78

Here’s what I’ve tried without any luck:

- Selecting the simulator -> Device -> Erase all content and settings.
- Updating all Nuget packages.
- Reinstalling Visual Studio 2019 for Mac, 8.9 build 265.
- Reinstalling Xcode 12.2.
- Reinstalling .NET Core SDK 3.1.403.
- Made sure my provisioning profiles are valid.
- Asked a colleague to run the same solution and he got the same problem.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hi, if you create a new xamarin forms project and run in release model, whether it works?

Comment: D'oh. A new project does in fact run without issue. I'm now trying to go back through previous commits to what should be a working build, but I'm still getting the same ambiguous message. :(

Comment: Okey, maybe it is caused by some nuget packages or other third party libraries, there are conflicts when running release model.